# Unable to chgrp or chown file from unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I am running into an odd issue trying to `chown` or `chgrp` a file from a unicorn process. Running the same code from `rails c`, it changes the group to the correct group, ex:

```
bash-$ whoami
zac

bash-$ groups
zachallett sysadmin

bash-$ ls -la
...
-rwxrw---- zac sysadmin 154 Nov 1 15:33 file.txt
...
```

rails controller action:

```
def controller
  file = "#{Rails.root}/file.txt"
  %x(chgrp zachallett #{file})
end
```

in unicorn log:

```
chgrp: changing group of `/var/www/app/current/file.txt': Operation not permitted
```

output of `ps aux | grep unicorn`:

```
zac    6579  0.0  1.1 254640 45188 ?        Sl   17:13   0:01 unicorn_rails master -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                               
zac    6582  0.0  1.0 254640 42704 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[0] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    6585  0.0  1.0 254640 42704 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    6588  0.0  1.0 254640 42704 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[2] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    6591  0.0  1.0 254640 42704 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[3] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    6594  0.0  1.1 254728 45004 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[4] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    6597  0.0  1.1 254728 45072 ?        Sl   17:13   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[5] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                            
zac    7274  0.0  0.0 103232   848 pts/0    S+   17:32   0:00 grep unicorn
```

Running the same chgrp from `rails c`, it changes the group just fine. So user `zac` owns the file, and is part of the `sysadmin` group, however I am unable to run `chgrp` on the file from a unicorn process.

**EDIT: Add unicorn.rb config file**

```
env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"

working_directory "/var/www/<APP>/current"
pid               "/var/www/<APP>/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path       "/var/www/<APP>/shared/log/unicorn/stderr.log"
stdout_path       "/var/www/<APP>/shared/log/unicorn/stdout.log"

listen            "/var/www/<APP>/shared/sockets/unicorn.socket"
worker_processes  env == "production" ? 6 : 2
timeout           120
preload_app       true
user              "zac", "sysadmin"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  old_pid = "/var/www/<APP>/shared/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"

  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # already killed
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it may be because from the file/application you are making the change is not having the `su` permission..try `chmod -R 777 your_app` and try again...I think this will help

Comment: Just for kicks, would you also post your unicorn config?

Comment: Updated original post to have my unicorn.rb file. A quick fix for now was to make the unicorn master run as root, while the child processes run as user `zac`